# How to make form class for 2 different entities using symfony 4?

Tags: php, forms, symfony4

Hello I am using Symfony 4,

I want to create a formClass which insert data for 2 different entities like 'vendor' and 'address'. Please explain me how can I create form class to accept data for 2 different entities via same form?

I have created form class which accepts data for only one entity but I am not getting to make formclass which accepts data for 2 different entities?

**Basically I am not getting to embed form together as one.**

Comment: do those entities overlap or should they be entered/displayed in the form side-by-side?

Comment: @Jakumi: they should be displayed as entries for the same form.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use entity type, make your own DTO(Data Transfer Object). I assume that both of these entities share some fields. So you can create a facade that'll help you with converting DTO to your entity types.

Make your DTO based on the request not on the actual entity, this has a great advantage because your code is less coupled and more flexible for changes in the future, it requires some additional work though. For example, yo'llu need to fill the DTO on your own and convert it back to the entities based on some strategy, in your case, it'd be vendor and access.

There's a nice article explaining how to do it in details you can look at it https://blog.martinhujer.cz/symfony-forms-with-request-objects/

Answer (score 0):

## combine the forms (preferred)

Assuming you have two entities `Vendor` and `Address` and forms for those entities `VendorType` and `AddressType`, you could create a form type `VendorAddressType` that, as a `buildForm` function has

```
$builder->add('vendor', VendorType::class)
        ->add('address', AddressType::class);
```

and when creating the `VendorAddressType` form you provide an array `['vendor' => $vendor, 'address' => $address]`. (you can similarly pass through options to the sub-forms). The `data_class` option for each subform can be the appropriate class, the `data_class` option for the combined form must be `null`.

now, in the normal symfony form templates, those forms are rendered differently from truly being in one form, but those templates could be extended, such that instead of `form_row`s, you call `form_widget` on `form.vendor` and `form.address` instead (see https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_themes.html#creating-a-form-theme-in-the-same-template-as-the-form)

## combine the forms, literally (not preferred)

Same assumption as before, you could copy the contents of each form type into the new VendorAddress form, and then set the `property_path` attribute for all fields to point to the respective entities, like:

```
$builder->add('vendorfieldA', SomeType::class, ['property_path' => 'vendor.fieldA'])
```

which will look into the provided data array (see before) at the key `vendor`, and select its property `fieldA`.

I would advise against this approach, since any changes to the single-entity forms must be repeated for the multiple-entity forms. Instead, I would advise to make static buildForm functions (adding a parameter `prefix` or something) which can be called from the combined form type via `VendorType::staticBuildForm($builder, $prefix)` (`$prefix = 'vendor.'`). (you have to transform that prefix into something you can append/prepend to the form field name as well, or provide that explicitly)